# How to manage a number of huge array pythonicly.

Tags: python, arrays, database, numpy

I'm a python user for scientific computation. Now, I have some numpy arrays, and the size of each of them is huge. Thus, I can not short all of them in the memory at the same time. I want to save the arrays in the disk and read them one by one at each time to do some calculation. How to perform this process pythonicly?

I know if all the data are stored in the memory, I can create a list named array_list like this:

```
array_list = []
for i0 in range(n_array):
    t_ayyay = do_some_calculate()
    array_list.append(t_ayyay)
```

and when I want to use them:

```
for i0 in range(n_array):
    t_ayyay = array_list[i0]
    # do something.
```

How to save array_list in the disk, and I can read each object using the index without load all of them in the memory?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe, you should try HDF5 and its python binding h5py http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/

Comment: Both `h5py` and `np.savez` save multiple arrays 'by-name'.  In other words, you access them by name, as though they were values in a dictionary.

Comment: oh, your suggestion works for me, thanks a lot. Is is possible to store all of them in one file?

Comment: Yes, as @hpaulj mentioned hdf5 files can store multiple datasets by keyword. Refeer to the h5py documentation for examples and more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pickle is your friend for serialization.

```
import pickle

some_list = [....]
pickle_out = open("some_list.pickle", "w")
pickle.dump(some_list, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

to open up your saved array

```
pickle_in = open("some_list.pickle", "r")
some_list = pickle.open(pickle_in)
```

Comment: `joblib` actually has better properties when it comes to serializing large numpy arrays.

Comment: Currently, the issue is, some_list is so big that I can NOT load it to the memory. And since I don't need all of them at the same time, I wander if there is a way I can unpick part of it once, like `some_list[i0]`, where `i0` is a index.

Comment: You may be more interested in [mem-maping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html), which lets you operate on the array while keeping it on disk.

Comment: @aryamccarthy, THX, great suggestion. Both packages are helpful for my project.